# vector capacity and Vector(int x, int y) method in java

Tags: java, vector, data-structures

This is the vector class that I have created,

```
Vector v= new Vector(3,2);
System.out.println("v.capacity: " +v.capacity());
v.addElement(new Integer(1));
v.addElement(new Integer(2));
v.addElement(new Integer(3));
v.addElement(new Integer(4));
System.out.println("v.size "+v.size());
System.out.println("v.capacity: " +v.capacity());
```

this shows result as :

v.capacity: 3

v.size 4

v.capacity: 5

if I change

```
Vector v= new Vector(7,2);
```

it gives

v.capacity: 7

v.size 4

v.capacity: 7

**So I want to know what is the actual output of this second capacity???Why the second out put didn't give me 9 as capacity size???**

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: "Why the second output didn't give me 9...": Because Why should it?  Why where you especially expecting 9? "..what is the actual output of this second capacity?": Well, 7.

Comment: Why would it be 9?  You haven't exceeded the initial capacity of 7!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first case, you declared a `Vector` with initial capacity of 3, and capacity increment of 2. Then, you proceeded to add 4 objects to that vector, surpassing its initial capacity of 3. The vector's new capacity is now its `old capacity` + `capacity increment`.

With your second case, you declared a `Vector` with initial capacity of 7 and capacity increment of 2. Then, adding 4 objects does not surpass its initial capacity of 7. Therefore, there is no need to increment its capacity yet, so it remains as 7. If you add 8 objects to your second vector you will see its new capacity will be 9.

Please look at the `Vector` documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Comment: alejandrogiron I got the point well and thanks for your explanation.